# How change the number of seconds Firefox audio video player seek back/forward with keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, html5

When you open an audio/video file with Firefox you can seek forward/backward 15 seconds with right/left keys. Is there a way to change that number or maybe even tweak the keyboard shortcuts? Ideally I want to be able to for example press `Shift+left/right` and it will go back/forward 5 seconds instead of 15 seconds.
Firefox official help [about this feature](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

The ability to configure media seek amount is not yet implemented in Firefox. See the discussion of this issue in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1474149.